# C++ class member initialization of std::vector<double[2]>

Tags: c++

I have a class like this

```
class A
{
    std::vector<double[2]> v;
}
```

I want to write a constructor like this

```
A::A()
    : v(10, {0.0, 0.0})
{
}
```

Which is (functionally) the same as this

```
v.reserve(10);
for(i ...)
{
    double t[2] = {0.0, 0.0};
    v[i][0] = t[0];
    v[i][1] = t[1];
}
```

However my attempt to write the constructor using the member initalization list syntax produces a compiler error. (Some long complex thing which involves a lot of STL I don't fully understand.)

Is initializing a `std::vector<double[2]>` possible using the syntax I am trying to use?

Comment: Isn't it allowed to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of `double[2]`?

Comment: A vector's elements most be movable (which can also mean copyable). A C-style array is neither movable or copyable. It can't serve as an element type. That's why `std::array` was standardized, to provide fixed sized arrays as regular value types.

Comment: why don't just use `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>`?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ... so - does that mean `std::vector<double[2]>` isn't permitted at all or that it just cannot be initialized in a STL like manner?

Comment: Not just initialized. You'll find practically all of the vector's operations can't work for that value type. It's basically unusable.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Do `operator[]`, and `at()` work?